# NoneType object is not subscriptable when extracting instagram comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

The following code tries to extract 10 instagram comments from 10 instagram posts using an Instagram scraper (https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper).
The error encountered is a TypeError (NoneType object is not subscriptable).

```
from igramscraper.instagram import Instagram
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import requests
instagram = Instagram()
pepsi = instagram.get_account('pepsi')
pepsi.media = instagram.get_medias("pepsi", 10)
p = [pp.__dict__ for pp in pepsi.media]
df = pd.DataFrame(p)
df['link']
comments_df=pd.DataFrame(columns = ["link","post_id", "comment"])

x1=10;

def get_media_id(url):

    req = requests.get('https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url={}'.format(url))

    media_id = req.json()['media_id']

    return media_id

 

def get_posts(link):

    id=get_media_id(link)

    comment0 = instagram.get_media_comments_by_id(id, 10)

    cdf=pd.DataFrame(columns = ["link","post_id", "comment"])

    for comment in comment0['comments']:

        cdf=cdf.append({"link":link,"post_id":id,"comment":comment.text},ignore_index = True)

    return cdf;   

   

       

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    comments_df=comments_df.append(get_posts(row["link"]), ignore_index = True)

   

comments_df
```

The problem I encounter is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-8e72850a113a> in <module>
     56 
     57 for index, row in df.iterrows():
---> 58     comments_df=comments_df.append(get_posts(row["link"]), ignore_index = True)
     59 
     60 

<ipython-input-27-8e72850a113a> in get_posts(link)
     41     id=get_media_id(link)
     42 
---> 43     comment0 = instagram.get_media_comments_by_id(id, 10)
     44 
     45     cdf=pd.DataFrame(columns = ["link","post_id", "comment"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? The error means that there is no data available.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing 'df' before accessing df['link'] to see if 'link' has any information inside.